# Fastboot doesn't see nexus 6p

Tags: adb, fastboot, bootloader, usb-drivers, android-sdk

Currently trying to unlock my bootloader, but cannot get my nexus 6p to determine that it's connected to my PC. I can use adb commands while it's on, but booting it into fastboot mode with the adb command or with the key combination results in 'connect usb data cable'. I have rebooted my phone, my computer, reinstalled ADB, installed the google drivers both manually as well as with the SDK manager and used 4 different cables.

I have also tried all 2 of my usb 2.0 ports as well as all 6 usb 3.0 ports.

Windows plays the sound confirming that a device has been connected.
I am using windows 10.

Here's a screenshot of the device manager:

Edit: Factory resetting the device did not help either.
[image: Device Manager]

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/110670/connect-usb-data-cable-message-on-fastboot-screen-preventing-recovery-reset-of

Comment: What does Device Manager show when the device is connected and the phone is booted in the bootloader?

Comment: @BoLawson there are no answers that work for me there.

Comment: @RMarkwald yes, but only as 'android device'

Comment: @RMarkwald Added a picture of device manager, and tried a factory reset.

Comment: Have you installed the Google Driver while in phone is booted to bootloader?  Those are in your SDK folder location - extras - google - usb_driver.  When my N6 is booted to bootloader, Windows 10 shows me the following:  http://i.imgur.com/DOrEyyr.png

Comment: @RMarkwald Amazing. Shows up now. Still says 'connect usb data cable' though - but it shows up in fastboot devies. Please write that as an answer, i will upvote and accept.

Comment: @Hellreaver Posted as answer, glad to hear it is working now for you.  I've been there before, pulling hair out trying to figure it out.  :)

Comment: @RMarkwald And it is quite often something simple like this. Although I'd rather it be dumbly simple that impossible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install the Google USB Driver while in phone is booted to bootloader.

Those are in your SDK folder location `- extras - google - usb_driver`.

When my N6 is booted to bootloader, Windows 10 shows me the following:

[image: Win10 Device Manager screenshot]