# Nexus 7 2013 not playing nice with Windows 10

Tags: nexus-7, windows

I did something to my Nexus 7 and need to transfer files via USB in recovery so I can reinstall my Android OS.

Unfortunately every time I plug it into the USB I get an error. In Device Manager I see my Nexus as "Unknown USB Device. Device Descriptor Request Failed." I try to manually install the drivers but they do not work.

I have searched the web and it seems like a compatibility issue between my newer USB 3 ports and the USB 2 standard of the Nexus 7. No matter how I try I can not get it working with the PC.

I have tried using a Kingwin USB hub and connecting the Nexus 7 through there without luck. I tried connecting to other Windows 10 machines (all ASUS) and have gotten the same error.

I tried entering ADB mode without luck. I tried getting the device to read a USB stick via OTG without success.

I can't find a Windows 7 machine to try and connect it to. I think that would work but I don't have one.

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: I can see the tablet in This PC and can "access" it, but what is shown is not the actual tablet contents but rather a generic set of empty folders which of course cannot be interacted with.

Answer (score 0):

What driver did you try installing?  Try installing the Google USB Driver which is in the Android SDK as outlined [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/136797/fastboot-doesnt-see-nexus-6p/136906#136906).  I am assuming you've got the Android SDK installed and setup on your computer?

Comment: This does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Google USB Driver](https://dl-ssl.google.com//android/repository/latest_usb_driver_windows.zip)

1. Extract
2. Doubleclick the file with .inf extension
3. Restart PC, Laptop or Tablet

*Note:* I can't guarantee the compatibility between the Nexus 7 and the Google USB Driver, since its made for these devices:

- ADP1 / T-Mobile G1*
- ADP2 / Google Ion / T-Mobile myTouch 3G*
- Verizon Droid*
- Nexus One and Nexus S

Comment: This driver has no more success than the default one.