# fastboot doesn´t see device but device manager & windows does

Tags: adb, rom-flashing, fastboot

I am trying to unlock the bootloader of my **Umidigi F1**.
ADB works, recognizes my phone but once I get into fastboot mode, `fastboot devices` does not display and devices.
I did install all the drivers and Windows itself does see an Android device,
and device manager does not show any unknown devices.
I have attached images of the devices Windows and the Device Manager find once I connect my phone in fastboot mode.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fastboot doesn't see nexus 6p](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/136797/fastboot-doesnt-see-nexus-6p)